# Grease pencil too dark render

Tags: eevee-render-engine, grease-pencil

[image][image]

EDIT:
Its supposed to look like the first image

Sorry if this is answered already i cant find the answer on the internet but im having a problem rendering this scene

This was the work around i found that works

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is too dark? Do you mean just the grease pencil outlines, or is the whole scene too dark?

Comment: the whole scene was too dark try added light but didnt work posted below what works for me

Comment: I do not understand the question. Was the image brighter when  before you render? Can you show a screengrab of that? Please use the [edit] link to modify your question  and add more details.

Comment: edited it @susu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Layer > Use Lights]

Uncheck **"Object Data properties > Layers > Use Lights"** for each layer.

This option was added in Blender 2.83. When **on**, GP object colors are affected by all lights. This means that if there are not enough light sources, the GP object will be dark.
When **off**, it will render the same color as selected in the Color Picker.

See Official manual: [Object — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.83/grease_pencil/object.html)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I dont know if this is the correct method but this one
works for me turn the world and viewport to white

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably due to default settings of default brush.
Its strength is by default 0.6. It means that strokes drawn with that brush will have an alpha multiplied by 0.6.

To solve the problem, go to sculpt mode and use the strength brush to give a value of 1 to strength of drawn strokes.
Or you can add an opacity modifier to BP object and set its factor above 1.
It is a pity that there is no global adjustment setting or operator to solve that kind of problem.

These defaults are very misleading.

Comment: thanks for the comment, i dont get it what about the fill colors though why is it dark